# function failed to execute in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function say667() {
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    var sayAlert = function() { alert(num); }
    num++;
    return sayAlert;
}

 say667();
```

what is wrong? I tried this code in jsfiddle, alert not pop out..

Comment: can you give jsfiddle link?

Comment: u can just write alert(num) if u just want to check the result. Please tell us more clearly

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be any good reason for returning a function from the function ?

Comment: @adeneo probably he's just experimenting... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just return function **reference**. You need to invoke it using `()` if you want it executed:

```
say667()();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/LTHP9/).

Comment: @Charlie74 yeah, JS does have its ugly side with pointers and references sometimes. :)

Comment: I got it now. I'm familier with something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LTHP9/1/ thx!!